# A performance concern when using minimizing a two-parameter function with scipy

Tags: python, performance, function, scipy, arguments

I have a 2-parameter python function

```
def foo(x,y):
          // a numeric operation that returns a double
```

I need to use scipy.optimize.minimize to locate a minimal point of f near a point, say (1.2, 3.4)

I have tried with

```
scipy.optimize.minimize(foo, (1.2, 3.4))

scipy.optimize.minimize(foo, [1.2, 3.4])
```

and

```
scipy.optimize.minimize(foo, *[1.2,3.4])
```

None of them works, yielding

```
TypeError: function takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

So my only solution seems to be wrapping the function, such as

```
scipy.optimize.minimize(lambda X:foo(*X), [1.2,3.4]),
```

The last one works, but I fear that the extra layer with the lambda term introduces unnecessary time overhead. Because my application is highly performance-sensitive, I am asking an efficient solution to let scipy.optimize.minimize accept a input pair for foo, without the  potential time overhead. Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should define your function in terms of a single (possibly multidimensional) argument. Thus you do not use

```
def foo(x,y):
      // a numeric operation that returns a double
```

but instead

```
def foo(x):
      // use x[0] in place of original x
      // and x[1] in place of original y
```

for example for f(x,y) = x + y^2 you use

```
def foo(x):
    return x[0] + x[1] ** 2
```

If you are not allowed to modify `foo` then you can always wrap it around with another function

```
def foowrap(x):
   return foo(x[0], x[1])
```

which should be slightly more efficient then unwraping list to positional arguments (* operator)

just to test

```
>>> timeit.timeit('foowrap([1,2])', setup='from __main__ import foowrap', number=10000000)
5.230706214904785    
>>> timeit.timeit('foo([1,2])', setup='from __main__ import foo', number=10000000) # this is your lambda term
5.379893779754639
```

so very small speedup, but it is.